# How do I stop VSCode from the Side Bar moving to the folder that the current file is in?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, whenever I close a file, the next open file becomes active in the editor and the Side Bar moves to that file's location in the folder structure. This is usually not the behavior I want. I often want to open another file in the same location as the one I just closed, but now my Side Bar has shifted around to what could be a totally different place in a large project.

I like the behavior of the main Visual Studio product where the Solution does not automatically shift. Instead, if I want to see where in the solution a file is, I can use a keyboard shortcut to move there ("Find File in Solution"), instead of automatically moving there every time the active file changes.

Is there any way to change/disable this functionality in VSCode?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The is an option `explorer.autoReveal` in settings (either user or workspace) which *controls if the explorer should automatically reveal files when opening them*.

1. Open VS User Settings (Preferences > User Settings). This will open two side-by-side documents.
2. Add a new `"explorer.autoReveal": false` setting to the User Settings document on the right if it's not already there. This is so you aren't editing the Default Setting directly, but instead adding to it.
3. Save the User Settings file.

Comment: If only there were a way to show the currently active file in the sidebar on command...

Comment: you can add a keyboard shortcut for: "Reveal active file in sidebar" in the settings, or right click on the file name and "Reveal in sidebar"

Comment: Except the instructions for opening User Settings does not do as advertised – no side-by-side docs anymore. They nerfed the settings. Now you have to do CTRL+SHIFT+P > settings (as JSON) and tap your head while rubbing your tummy.

Answer (score 24):

in Version: 1.42.1

1. Open VS User Settings (Preferences > User Settings).
2. Search for "explorer auto reveal" without quotes.
3. Now uncheck the checkbox.

[image: Uncheck this]

Answer (score 22):

There is a new setting in v1.46 that will select the files in the explorer but not scroll to reveal them:

> There is a new option `focusNoScroll` for the `explorer.autoReveal` setting. When using this option, the Explorer will automatically select files when opening them but will not scroll to reveal them in the Explorer view.

from [v1.46 release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#explorer-auto-reveal-focus-without-forcing-a-scroll).

So that setting will highlight the active editor in the explorer but not scroll to it.

Comment: This is very helpful when deleting files using the Explorer but you want to continue working in that part of the file tree.